# Create array with all unique combinations

Tags: javascript

Can't figure out how to create an array with all matches. I suppose I need a recursive function for this.

I like to get all values from the JSON below and create an array with all value combinations.
There may be more or less models (Name4) and more or less values.
Any help?

```
var models = [
    {
        name: 'Name1',
        values: [
            'Title1Value1',
            'Title1Value2',
            'Title1Value3'
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Name2',
        values: [
            'Title2Value1',
            'Title2Value2'
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Name3',
        values: [
            'Title3Value1',
            'Title3Value2'
        ]
    }
];

// Output array
var matches = [
    [ 'Title1Value1', 'Title2Value1', 'Title3Value1' ],
    [ 'Title1Value1', 'Title2Value1', 'Title3Value2' ],
    [ 'Title1Value1', 'Title2Value2', 'Title3Value1' ],
    [ 'Title1Value1', 'Title2Value2', 'Title3Value2' ],
    [ 'Title2Value2', 'Title2Value1', 'Title3Value1' ],
    [ 'Title1Value2', 'Title2Value1', 'Title3Value2' ],
    [ 'Title1Value2', 'Title2Value2', 'Title3Value1' ],
    [ 'Title1Value2', 'Title2Value2', 'Title3Value2' ],
    [ 'Title1Value3', 'Title2Value1', 'Title3Value1' ],
    [ 'Title1Value3', 'Title2Value1', 'Title3Value2' ],
    [ 'Title1Value3', 'Title2Value2', 'Title3Value1' ],
    [ 'Title1Value3', 'Title2Value2', 'Title3Value2' ]
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var indices = [];
var lengths = [];
for (i = 0; i<models.length; i++) {
    indices[i] = 0;
    lengths[i] = models[i].values.length;
}
var matches = [];
while (indices[0] < lengths[0]) {
    var row = [];
    for (i = 0; i<indices.length; i++) {
       row.push(models[i].values[indices[i]]);
    }
    matches.push(row);
    /* Cycle the indexes */
    for (j = indices.length-1; j >= 0; j--) {
        indices[j]++;
        if (indices[j] >= lengths[j] && j != 0) {
            indices[j] = 0;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```