# javascript increment numerical array

Tags: javascript

We have a numerical array with arbitrary max values for each element. How do we increment the elements so the array would go from `[0, 0, 0]` to `[x, y, z]`?

To illustrate if the max array is `[2, 1, 2]` and we start the main array at `[0, 0, 0]` incrementing should take the main array through these steps:

```
[0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0]
[2, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 0]
[2, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 1]
[2, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 2]
[1, 0, 2]
[2, 0, 2]
[0, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 2]
[2, 1, 2]
```

I have written a function which stops incrementing as soon as it reaches a max of 1. Here is my code:

```
var maxes = [2, 1, 2];
var myArray = [0, 0, 0];

function step() {
  for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if(myArray[i] == maxes[i]) {
       continue;
    } else {
       myArray[i] = myArray[i] + 1;
       return;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

for(j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
  result = step();
  if(!result) break;
  console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: it is hard to follow the pattern you are looking for, are you trying to calculate with base(4) ? You should at least provide a mathematical formulas to follow.

Comment: @MehdiKaramosly, the *formula* is simple, increment the leftmost element that is still below the max for that element. If all elements are at their maxes, return false.

Comment: You can use a simplified version of my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13742093/create-array-with-all-unique-combinations/13742505#13742505

Comment: @Shredder, actually this could be thought of as a base `n` number with two exceptions (i) each digit has it's own base which is the max, and (ii) we are writing the number right to left.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote any answers that helped you and accept an answer if it solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Fair disclosure: This is my own question. I did not have access to my SO or email logins and posted this question with a new account just then created for a friend. I am not upvoting the question or him the answer. Neither would I have my friend mark my answer as accepted. Anyway, I worked on the problem and eventually came by this working code:

```
var maxes = [4,1,2,3];
var pattern = [0,0,0,0];

function step() {
  var t = false;
  for(var k = 0; k < pattern.length; k++) {
    t = t || (pattern[k] < maxes[k]);
  }
  if(!t) return false;
  for(k = 0; k < pattern.length; k++) {
    if(pattern[k] < maxes[k]) {
      pattern[k]++;
      return true;
    } else {
      pattern[k] = 0;
      continue;
    }
    return false;
  }
}

console.log(pattern);
var r = true;
while(r) {
  r = step();
  console.log(pattern);
}
```

JSBin [here](http://jsbin.com/ucagoj/1/edit).

Answer (score 0):

You need two loops - one for each `maxes` element, 4 of them currently, but I'm not sure if you plan to change it to be dynamic; and the other loop that will increment values of each element until it reaches its limit value from `maxes`.

Answer (score 0):

You just have some bugs to work out:

```
var maxes   = [3, 1, 2, 1];
var myArray = [0, 0, 0, 0];

function step() {
  var changed = false;
  for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if(myArray[i] == maxes[i]) {
       continue;
    } else {
       myArray[i] = myArray[i] + 1;
       changed = true;
    }
  }
  return changed;
}

for(j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
  result = step();
  if(!result) break;
  console.log(myArray.join(", "));
}
```

Comment: What did you change and why did you change it?

Comment: I removed the `return` from the middle of the loop, and I added the variable `changed`. When you return nothing, it's equivalent to returning `false`, thus causing your loop (at the bottom) to `break`.

Comment: @redolent your code is not outputting anything ! except  true 3 times.

Comment: OK I just edited the code. I am now logging myArray.join() which will print the contents of the array.

Answer (score 0):

I revisited this problem a few days ago, and refactored the code a bit.

First to understand the problem properly, it is equivalent to counting in a hybrid-base number system. In this system we have an arbitrary base per position/digit. If all the maxes are 2 for instance the problem then would be counting in base-2, but the maximum for each position could be a different number, hence, the *hybrid* base system.

The central function is actually very simple:

```
// increment in hyper system
function incr(maxes,num,digit) {
  num[digit] = num[digit] + 1;
  num[digit] = num[digit] % (maxes[digit]+1);
  if(num[digit] === 0) incr(maxes,num,digit+1);
}
```

And here's a working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ujipaq/1/).

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simpler, more efficient solution: Simply take a variable *pos* that stores the current position in the array. Once we've reached max at the current position, we increment the current position by 1, otherwise increment the value at the current position.
And that process you just keep repeating until *pos* has reached the last value **and** the last value is at max.

```
var maxes = [3, 1, 2, 1];
var myArray = [0, 0, 0, 0];
var pos = 0;

while (pos < myArray.length - 1 || myArray[pos] < maxes[pos]) {
    if (myArray[pos] >= maxes[pos]) {
        myArray[pos] = 0; // to set it back to zero
        pos++;
        continue;
    } 
    myArray[pos]++;

    // Step code here
}
```

Works with any sized array. Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brXnB/)

Comment: Thank you, but the output is not correct. From `3,0,0,0` we should go to `0,1,0,0` not `3,1,0,0`

Comment: the result doesn't look like the example he gave /

Comment: Ow k. Then we'll just add the line "myArray[pos] = 0;" to reset the value again.

Comment: I would only miss a return if it were a javascript function, but it's not. According to the original question it should only stop at max, not return anything. I clarified now where the step code should go.

Comment: yes and the max should be in the above case : [3,1,2,1]
and with the edit I have made to your code(in order to set to zero when it reaches the max) it gives : [0,0,0,1]

Comment: Incorrect answer. This code (using your JSFiddle example) doesn't produce the desired output. It only increments each individual index value from 0 to its own max, without accounting for the subvariants, like [1,1,0,0].